# problemas viewdata y morris.js

Tags: javascript, c#, vb.net, controller

```
<script>
        $.widget.bridge('uibutton', $.ui.button);
        new Morris.Line({
            // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
            element: 'myfirstchart',
            // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
            // the chart.
            data: [
                { year: '2000', value: 5 },
                { year: '2011', value: 5 },
                { year: '2012', value: 20 },
                { year: '2013', value: 2 } 


estos valores debo reemplazarlo por informacion que viene de mi controlador , en mi controlador asigno un resultado asi  ViewData["cant3"] = 1000;
como puedo reemplzar los valores que estan en year :'2000', value 5 por lo que trae Viewdata
```

],
// The name of the data record attribute that contains x-values.
xkey: 'year',
// A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-values.
ykeys: ['value'],
// Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the
// chart.
labels: ['Value']
});